# Android list view task to edit text

Tags: android, database, listview

I have an android ListView Application Which is connected to a database. I want to have have somebody be able to edit the listView they click on. When They long click, it brings them two a different activity with a text view and a save button. What I want is for the the textview to have the text Of the item it is editing.

For example:

```
 Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
            b.putExtra(Rd, String.valueOf(id));
```

Takes The Database Row Id and Makes it into a string ^

```
// Puts Id Of Last Clicked List View Item Into String//
public final static String Rd = DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID;
```

Takes the string and makes it global ^

```
    // Gets Id Of Last Clicked List View Item//
    passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Rd);

    // Links Variable etTasks To Physical Edit Text In Layout//
    etTasks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTask);
    etTasks.setText(passedVar);
```

which Then allows the number or ROW_ID to be viewd in the edit text ^

I want to do the same thing but with the text content in the list view item not the row id of the database. Please Help Thanks.

Here is rest of my code.

DBAdapter:

```
public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging 
database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TASK, KEY_DATE};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
public static final int COL_DATE = 2;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbToDo";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainToDo";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TASK + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT"
        + ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String task, String date) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(String rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(String rowId, String task, String date) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
      }
  }


}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements   
.OnClickListener {

// Connect To Database MyDb//
DBAdapter myDb;

// Defines Variable ListView MyList//
ListView mylist;

// Defines Variable ListView Adapter//
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;

// Defines Variable Database Cursor//
Cursor cursor;

// Defines Variable Connected To Database String//
String[] fromFieldNames;

// Defines Variable That Takes String From Database//
int[] toViewIDs;

// Puts Id Of Last Clicked List View Item Into String//
public final static String Rd = DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID;

// Puts Task Of Last Clicked List View Item Into String//
public final static String Sd = DBAdapter.KEY_TASK;

// What Happens When Activity Starts//
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Links Variable MyList To Physical ListView In Layout//
    mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Links Variable Button2 to Physical Button In Layout//
    Button option = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    option.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Controls What Happens When ListView Is Long Clicked//
    mylist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

            Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
            b.putExtra(Rd, String.valueOf(id));
            b.putExtra(Sd, String.valueOf(toViewIDs));
            startActivity(b);

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Opens Database//
    openDB();

    // Shows Whats Stored In Database In A List View//
    populateListView();
}

// What Happens When Said Button Is Clicked//
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        // What Happens When Button Two Is Clicked//
        case R.id.button2:

            // Open Activity Test//
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Test.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}

// Method To Open Database//
private void openDB() {

    // Links Variable myDb To Database//
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);

    // Opens Database//
    myDb.open();
}

// Method To Populate ListViews From Database//
private void populateListView() {

    // Gets All Rows Added To Database//
    cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    // Puts Rows Stored On Database Into A String (DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID = Numbers Each Row In ListView, KEY_TASK = Information Shown By You//
    fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_TASK,};

    // Takes String From Database And Sends It To Whatever Layout Widget You Want. Will Show Up In The Order String Is Made In//
    toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.textViewItemNumber, R.id.textViewItemTask};

    // Creates ListView Adapter Which Allows ListView Items To Be Seen//
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);

    // Sets Up Adapter Made Earlier / Shows Content From Database//
    mylist.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
  }

}
```

Test.class:

```
public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {

// Sets Item In ListView To The Current Date It Mas Made//
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());

// Connect To Database//
DBAdapter myDb;

// Defines Variable EditText//
public static EditText etTasks;

public static TextView passedView;

String passedVar = null;

String passedVar2 = null;

// Defines String Variable For Date In Update Task//
String date;

// Defines String Variable For Task In Update Task//
String task;

// Defines Variable Database Cursor//
Cursor cursor;

// What Happens When Activity Starts//
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    // Gets Id Of Last Clicked List View Item//
    passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Rd);

    // Gets Id Of Last Clicked List View Item//
    passedVar2 = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Sd);

    // Links Variable etTasks To Physical Edit Text In Layout//
    etTasks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTask);
    etTasks.setText(passedVar2);

    //Opens DataBase//
    openDB();
}

// Method To Open Database//
private void openDB() {

    // Links Variable myDb To Database//
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);

    // Opens Database//
    myDb.open();
}

// What Happens When Add Button Is Clicked//
public void onClick_AddTask(View v) {

    // Set New Database Entry To Current Time//
    today.setToNow();

    // Sets Time In Format Understandable To Humans//
    String timestamp = today.format("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    // Takes Whats In Edit Text And Turns It Into A String//
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etTasks.getText().toString())) {

        // Inserts It Into Database//
        myDb.insertRow(etTasks.getText().toString(), timestamp);
    }

    // Sets PassedView To Null//
    passedView = null;

    // Starts Options Activity//
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

// What Happens When Add Button Is Clicked//
public void editListView(View v) {

    updateTask(DEFAULT_KEYS_DIALER);
}

// Method That Updates Task//
private void updateTask(long id) {

        // Gets Selected Row//
        cursor = myDb.getRow(passedVar);

        // Where New Updated Content Comes From//
        task = etTasks.getText().toString();

        // Set New Database Entry To Current Time//
        today.setToNow();

        // Sets Time In Format Understandable To Humans//
        date = today.format("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

        // Updates Specific Row In Database//
        myDb.updateRow(passedVar, task, date);

        // Closes Cursor//
        cursor.close();

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
     }
  }
```

Comment: What is exactly your question/problem?

Comment: I cant get the text in my listview to show up in my edit text box

Comment: On your test.class after you do getStringExtra of passedVar on the onCreate() write Log.d("DEBUG", "passedVar---> "+passedVar) and check what is written on the log.